# 502 Bad gateway flask application deployed in AWS EB

Tags: flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep on getting error 502 bad gateway in my flask application that I'm trying to deploy to AWS. At the root of my folder, I have a file application.py, which contains:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api

from api.user_endpoints import (
    bp_api, #This is a blueprint
    SignUp
)

application = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(bp_api)

api.add_resource(SignUp, '/v1.0/signup/')

application.register_blueprint(bp_api, url_prefix='/api')

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

This is one of my logs:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Nov 24 23:10:47 ip-172-31-11-56 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Nov 24 23:10:47 ip-172-31-11-56 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Nov 24 23:10:47 ip-172-31-11-56 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Nov 24 23:10:47 ip-172-31-11-56 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

When running "eb config" from the command line, I have:

```
WSGIPath: application:application.py
```

I tried

```
WSGIPath: application.py
```

and

```
WSGIPath: application
```

but I always get the same result. How to solve this situation, or at least how to troubleshoot it better?

**Edit:** Here is the content of my requirements.txt:

```
wheel
flask
flask_login
flask_sqlalchemy
flask_bcrypt
flask_babel
flask_restful
flask_wtf
flask_api
pandas
joblib
boto3
sklearn
requests
email_validator
authlib
pyarmor
mysql-connector
uwsgi
supervisor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to **replicate** your issue using `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running Python 3.7`, but it **all works** for me. To test I had to remove the `api.user_endpoints` parts from your code as I don't have them, but no other changes were required.

Also there was no need to modify `WSGIPath`. So whatever is happening for you, its something not shown in your question.

Comment: I've added edited my question and added the content of "requirements.txt"

Comment: @Brainless I'm getting error ` No module named 'api'` with your code. If you can't provide fully self-contained reproducible code, I can't help much more.